# Custom Pydantic classes as FastAPI body parameters

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

[Pydantic says](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types) that you can create custom classes by simply defining the `__get_validators__` method. This is useful if you want to parse into a class with its own metaclass or for some other reason do not want to inherit from `BaseModel`.

However, this fails in strange places in FastAPI. For example, FastAPI does not detect such a class as a body parameter, but always thinks it is a query parameter.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()

class NastyMetaClass(type):
    pass

class Foo(metaclass=NastyMetaClass):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield lambda value: True

@app.post("/implicit")
def foo(foo: Foo):  # This is supposed to work, but does not
    return "It worked"

@app.post("/explicit")
def foo_body(foo: Foo = Body(...)):  # The `= Body(...)` fixes it
    return "It worked"

client = TestClient(app)

response = client.post("/implicit", json={})
print(response.json())
# {'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'foo'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}

response = client.post("/explicit", json={})
print(response.json())
# It worked
```

How can I make FastAPI recognize custom Pydantic classes?

Answer (score 0):

As per [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body), when using `Body(...)`, you instruct FastAPI to treat a parameter as body. Thus, using `foo: Foo = Body(...)` is one way to tell your endpoint to expect a `JSON` body with the attributes of `Foo`.

Alternatively, you could delcare the `Foo` parameter using [Dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/), as shown below. You could even simply use `Depends()` (i.e., `foo: Foo = Depends()`) as a [shortcut](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#shortcut) to avoid code repetition.

```python
from fastapi import Depends

@app.post("/implicit")
def foo(foo: Foo = Depends(Foo)):  # This should work
    return "It worked"
```

Also, the reason for your `/implicit` route expecting `foo` as a query parameter instead, is that your `Foo` class does **not** inherit from `BaseModel`, which would tell FastAPI to treat it as body. Hence, you should have a class inheriting from `BaseModel`, where you define your `foo` parameter, and use that model in your endpoint, as demonstrated in Pydantic's [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types). Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class Model(BaseModel):
    foo: Optional[Foo] = None
    
@app.post("/implicit")
def foo(m: Model):
    return "It worked"
```